# React Native application with Push notification capability crashes on start

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

I'am trying to receive push notification with `react-native-fcm`. As documentation says I'am install and implement all steps as bellow

a) Install react-native-fcm `npm install react-native-fcm --save`

b) Link the library with `react-native link react-native-fcm`

c) Download `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from firebase console and place it in /ios/my-project directory

d) Install Firebase Messaging with Cocoapods
 1. cd ios && pod init
 2. add `pod 'Firebase/Messaging'` into `Podfile`
 3. `pod install`

e) Edit `AppDelegate.h`

```
@import UserNotifications;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
/*@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>*/
```

f) Edit `AppDelegate.m`

```
#import "RNFIRMessaging.h"
//...

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  //...
  [FIRApp configure];
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];

   return YES;
}


-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler
{
  [RNFIRMessaging willPresentNotification:notification withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

#if defined(__IPHONE_11_0)
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveNotificationResponse:response withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
#else
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveNotificationResponse:response withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
#endif

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification 
{
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

g) Enable capabilities

1. Push Notifications
2. Background Modes > Remote notifications

Then I archive my application in `ipa` and try to start it on device. Application crashes after loading screen appear. Please, explan to me, where is my mistake?

PS. No one `.js` file are not change from `create-react-native-app` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the notes , he has explain as why you should  switch to react-native-firebase

[NOTES of react native fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm#notes)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but current `react-native-fcm` should also work

Comment: I'am find why application is crashes due to you link. Thank you very much, React-native-firebase is awesome too!